# Getting NaN while using GridSearchCV in regression machine learning problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been using below code for hyper parameter tuning using GridSearchCV and it is not showing any error while fitting the gridsearchcv, however I'm getting only 'NaN' as output values. I tried to traceback this code by adding/removing lines of codes one by one, but its not helping.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

def find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(X,y):
    algos = {'linear regression': {'model': LinearRegression(),'params': {'normalize': [True, False]}},
        'lasso': {'model': Lasso(),'params': {'alpha': [1,2],'selection': ['random','cyclic']}},
        'decision tree': {'model': DecisionTreeRegressor(),'params':{'criterion': ['mse', 'friedman_mse'],'splitter': ['best','random']}}}
    scores = []
    cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=10)
    for algo_name, config in algos.items():
        gs = GridSearchCV(config['model'], config['params'], cv=cv, return_train_score=False,error_score='raise')
        gs.fit(X,y)
        scores.append({
            'model': algo_name,
            'best_score': gs.best_score_,
            'best_params': gs.best_params_
        })
        
    return pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['Model', 'Best Score', 'Best Paramters'])

find_best_model_using_gridsearchcv(X,y)
```

**Output:**

```
    Model   Best Score  Best Paramters
0   NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `columns=['Model', 'Best Score', 'Best Paramters']`
from the line  `return pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['Model', 'Best Score', 'Best Paramters'])`

and you should get what you're looking for.

Since you're passing a list of dictionaries with identical keys to `pd.DataFrame()` there is no need to pass column names.